# Using IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA with Greenplum database

Tags: postgresql, greenplum, foreign-data

I have setup a PostgreSQL 12 database and am trying to connect to a Greenplum database in order to create proxy tables.  I am able to connect to the Greenplum db, but I get an error when I try to use the IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA command.

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA remote_schema FROM SERVER "remote_server" INTO schema_test_1;
```

returns:

```
    ERROR:  Greenplum Database does not support REPEATABLE READ transactions. (variable.c:570)
CONTEXT:  remote SQL command: START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
SQL state: XX000
```

I read that REPEATABLE READ is not supported in Greenplum and to use SERIALIZE instead.  Is there a way to edit the IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA command so that I can replace REPEATABLE READ with SERIALIZE?

I am using PGadmin 4.

Update:

I found that I can get commands to work if I write them as complete transactions and include the following before any commands:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

Is there a way to set this as the default value for all transactions going through the Foreign Server?

Comment: Looks like you have created two accounts see https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0):

No, that cannot be done. You have to use a less ancient fork of PostgreSQL that has heard of `REPEATABLE READ`.

To make that work, you'd have to modify the PostgreSQL source code, but if you do you should use `SERIALIZABLE` only with Greenplum.

Answer (score 0):

Per F.31.3 of PostgreSQL 9.5 docs:

> The remote transaction uses SERIALIZABLE isolation level when the
>   local transaction has SERIALIZABLE isolation level; otherwise it uses
>   REPEATABLE READ isolation level.

If you change the postgresql.conf file to

```
default_transaction_isolation = 'SERIALIZABLE'
```

it will use SERIALIZABLE vice REPEATABLE READ transaction isolation when communicating with foreign servers.

Queries to the foreign server work fine now, including IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA.